# Read messages from different SQS queues in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, amazon-sqs

I have 2 separate Amazon SQS queues; Queue and ResponseQueue.

SQS configurations:

```xml
<sqs:config name="Amazon_SQS_Consumer" accessKey="XXX" secretKey="XXX" queueName="Queue" doc:name="Amazon SQS">
    <sqs:connection-pooling-profile maxActive="10" maxIdle="10" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW" maxWait="12000" minEvictionMillis="60000" evictionCheckIntervalMillis="30000" initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ONE"/>
    <reconnect count="5" frequency="1000"/>
</sqs:config>   
<sqs:config name="Amazon_SQS_Response" accessKey="XXX" secretKey="XXX" queueName="ResponseQueue" doc:name="Amazon SQS">
    <sqs:connection-pooling-profile maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW" maxWait="12000" minEvictionMillis="60000" evictionCheckIntervalMillis="30000" initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ONE"/>
    <reconnect count="5" frequency="1000"/>
</sqs:config>
```

I have no problem receiving messages from the first queue (Queue) via:

```xml
<flow name="consumer" doc:name="consumer">
    <sqs:receive-messages config-ref="Amazon_SQS_Consumer" preserveMessages="true" doc:name="Amazon SQS (Streaming)" visibilityTimeout="300" />
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[payload]" />
</flow>
```

I need to also receive messages from the second queue (ResponseQueue):

```xml
<flow name="response" doc:name="response">
    <sqs:receive-messages config-ref="Amazon_SQS_Response" preserveMessages="true" doc:name="Amazon SQS (Streaming)" visibilityTimeout="300" />
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[payload]" />
</flow>
```

However, whenever the second `sqs:receive-messages` is added, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Receiving Thread" java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  org/mule/module/launcher/plugin/MulePluginsClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/amazonaws/services/sqs/QueueUrlHandler"
```

Is it possible to read messages from 2 different queues in the same project?

I'm using `3.4.0 CE` Mule Server Runtime and `2.4.4` Amazon SQS Connector. **I need to stay at these versions**. If I switch to `3.5.0 EE` Mule Server Runtime, there is no problem in having multiple `sqs:receive-messages`; it works just as expected. However, it [leads to another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892731/jetty-in-mule-only-works-in-earlier-version-of-studio).

Comment: I should have asked earlier: were you getting this exception when running your application on Studio, on Mule, on both?

Comment: @DavidDossot Just Studio.

Comment: OK, people have reported similar issues with plain Spring projects on Eclipse. Cleaning the project and rebuilding it seems to solve the issue.

Comment: @DavidDossot I can receive messages from the 2 queues fine when using Mule Server Runtime `3.5.0 EE` with SQS `2.5.0`, but not in `3.4.0 CE` with SQS `2.4.4` like I need to...

Comment: Mmmh yes, SQS `2.5.0` expects Mule `3.5.0` (see: https://github.com/mulesoft/sqs-connector/blob/mule-module-sqs-2.5.0/pom.xml ). I guess you'll have to build a `3.5.0 CE` distribution yourself from source code so you can deploy your app.

Comment: @DavidDossot There is no way to receive messages via `sqs:receive-messages` for more than 1 queue in a given project?

Comment: There should be no limitation to the number of `receive-messages` element so it's a bug IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same credentials in both `sqs:config` elements? If yes, then you only need one `config` element and then specify the queue name on the `sqs:receive-messages` elements.

```
<sqs:receive-messages queueName="Queue"
                      preserveMessages="true"
                      visibilityTimeout="300" />
```

Refer to the user guide: http://mulesoft.github.io/sqs-connector/2.5.0/mule/sqs-config.html#receive-messages

Comment: Yes, the credentials are the same. Can you give me an example of that `sqs:receive-messages` element?

Comment: I tried the code you posted, but it gives the following message:
`Required attribute config-ref is not defined in receive-messages`
However the guide states that the `config-ref` attribute is optional.

Comment: What gives this error? Mule on start-up or Studio? If the latter, disregard, Studio is known to give bogus validation errors. Or add `config-ref="Amazon_SQS_Consumer"` if this really annoys you.

Comment: Studio. Even with `config-ref`, when the `queueName` attribute is added I get the following error: `Attribute 'queueName' is not allowed to appear in element 'sqs:receive-messages'`. Same thing when adding the `queueUrl` attribute which is also shown in the guide.

Comment: Sanity checking: are you using version `2.5.0` of the SQS connector? If yes, then this is probably a bug worth reporting to MuleSoft...

Comment: I'm using the "Amazon SQS Connector" version `2.4.4`. While checking for updates, it indicates that there are none. I followed the installation instructions [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/connectors/amazon-sqs).

Comment: The Maven artifact and Studio plugin are here: https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/modules/mule-module-sqs/2.5.0/