# Jetty in Mule only works in earlier version of Studio

Tags: jetty, mule, mule-studio

I'm having problems using the Jetty connectors in Mule.

Within my `mule` configuration:

```xml
<jetty:connector name="JettyRest" configFile="jetty-rest.xml" doc:name="Jetty" />
<jetty:connector name="JettySoap" configFile="jetty-soap.xml" doc:name="Jetty" />
```

There is no problem at all when running in Mule Studio (using Mule Server Runtime `3.4.0 CE`). However, after importing the project to and running in Anypoint Studio (using Mule Server Runtime `3.5.0 CE`), I get the following error:

```
Cannot load class 'org.mortbay.jetty.Server'
```

Even if I manually include the [Jetty JAR from here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty) to the build path, I get this error:

```
Object of class 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server' is not of type 'org.mortbay.jetty.Server'. Object Class and type Class are from different loaders.
```

The same issue is present when running with Mule standalone `3.4.0 CE` vs `3.5.0 CE`.

In `jetty-rest.xml`:

```xml
<Configure id="Server" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server">
```

In `jetty-soap.xml`:

```xml
<Configure id="ServerForSlow" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server">
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Jetty transport or is it a third party connector? The link about the instructions doesn't work.

Comment: @AleSequeira It's the Mule Jetty connector. And it appears that instruction page I linked has been removed within the last 20 minutes.

Comment: Why not to use Jetty Transport, which is a Mule supported transport?

Comment: @AleSequeira I meant the Jetty transport. If I don't include the Jetty JAR, I get the error `Cannot load class 'org.mortbay.jetty.Server'`. This doesn't happen at all in the earlier version of Mule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to discover what causes the issue. The Mule `3.5.0 CE` Jetty transport now uses Jetty 8, and I was previously using Jetty 6 with Mule `3.4.0 CE`.

Within `MIGRATION.txt`:

```
MULE-7061: Jetty transport is now using Jetty 8. Applications using a custom jetty.xml configuration file must update the Jetty classes referenced in this file due to package names changed from version 6 to 7, as explained here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Starting/Porting_to_Jetty_7/Packages_and_Classes
```

After following the [instructions in the link provided](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Starting/Porting_to_Jetty_7/Packages_and_Classes) I converted my files to use Jetty 8.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to add the Jetty JAR yourself: they should be brought in your project as part of the Mule Jetty Transport, which is very much an officially supported core transport:

- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Jetty+Transport+Reference
- https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/tree/mule-3.x/transports/jetty

Was the Jetty transport added to your build path / POM file by Studio?

Comment: In the original project using Mule Studio (Mule Server `3.4.1`), I did not have to add the Jetty JAR. However, after importing that project to Anypoint Studio (Mule Server `3.5.0`), I get the error `Cannot load class 'org.mortbay.jetty.Server'`. That's why I tried to add the Jetty JAR, which now gives the error indicated in my question.

Comment: The Jetty transport should have brought this JAR. Is the Jetty transport in your project build path / POM?

Comment: The `Mule Server 3.5.0 EE` library contains a number of Jetty JARs... However, `pom.xml` doesn't seem to contain any Jetty configurations.

Comment: Not even the Jetty transport with `provided` scope?

Comment: No, the only `provided` scope is for groupId `org.apache.httpcomponents`.

Comment: Another question: does the application run on Mule itself? Or does it fail also when you deploy on Mule?

Comment: It doesn't start the app; shortly after `Initializing app 'project-name'`, I get the error. The same result for both.

Comment: Feels like a bug then: open a JIRA or contact MuleSoft support directly.